# How to setup pi to save files on PC directly via USB?

Tags: data-transfer

So my Pi has very little processing power. I need to use my PC for it. So how do i make a quick automatic transfer of files generated in a folder from Pi to PC (doing it over FTP might be a way but is there a faster, more direct route? Or can i save it to PC over FTP directly?)

Comment: What operating system is on the PC?

Comment: Windows 8.1 with cygwin.

Comment: If ubuntu is the only way i am willing to change.

Comment: You can mount a `Samba` share in Windows (i.e. "map" a drive), and that will "look" like another drive on your Windows machine. Setting up a Samba server is not difficult, but will take up most of an afternoon if you've not done it before. There are lots of "how-to" guides for setting up a Samba server ([this is one I did](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md)), just ask Google for "samba server raspberry pi".

Comment: Thanks seamus i will check your guide out!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use *FTP* over USB? So I assume you have a Raspberry Pi Zero with a OTG gadget connection using ethernet mode (g_ether).

Then you can install a **samba server** on the RasPi. With it you can open network shares of directories on the RasPi. Then you are able to connect to the "network directories" from the MS Windows PC as usual. Just accessing the files on the network share is a quick automatic transfer of files generated in a folder from Pi to PC.

You can also use a OTG gadget connection using mass storage mode (g_mass_storage). Then you can connect to the "removable media" like any other USB storage and use the files stored on it.

Comment: Already did. Will set the shared folder!